# Maximal interval of existence - ODE - Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Another day and another problem. I am having a difficult time trying to solve the following problem:
Determine the maximal interval of exsitence $(0,T^+)$.

$$
y^\prime = e^{-t^2}+ y^2,\\
y(0)=1
$$

Every tip/hint would help me and I would appreciate it :-)

Comment: You can easily get $\tan(\frac\pi4+t)\le y(t)\le \frac1{1-t}$, but that gives only an interval for $T^+$. What exactly is the specification for "determine $T^+$"?

Comment: Finding an exact solution seems difficult, but you could let $z(t)=1/y(t)$ and solve the resulting ODE for $z$ numerically to determine $T^+$ from the condition $z(T^+)=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have to determine the maximum existence intervall

Comment: @HansLundmark This problem is consideredefor an exam, where I am not allowd to use any kind of numerical help.

Comment: A non-numerical solution appears to be quite impossible. Do you have any similar problems as reference? $y'=t^2+y^2$ is quite popular. /// You can also try to determine the solution to $u''(t)+e^{-t^2}u(t)=0$ with $u(0)=1$, $u'(0)=-1$, and try to determine its first positive root.